# How can I unlock my Lenovo A7700 pattern lock which I forgot the pattern?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lock-screens, locked-out, lenovo, pattern-lock

I use pattern lock on my Lenovo A7700 running Android 6.0 Marshmallow, but today I forget my pattern.

How can I unlock my phone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform a hard reset, but this will remove all your personal data. You could have a look  [here](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/lenovo/lenovo-a7000/)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to keep data, but you have to install a custom recovery.

Refer: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/remove-lockscreen-recovery-t3530008

Comment: altough it is possible to flash [TWRP](https://www.getdroidtips.com/twrp-recovery-lenovo-a7700) from SP Flash Tool it might fail to boot on locked bootloader, most Lenovo devices have secure boot enabled